# Passing email value to URL in contour umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-contour

I have a Request Quote for in Umbraco using Contour and upon submitting successfully this form, the use is redirected to a Thank You Page (In settings in the Contour, i'm using "$currentPage/* [@isDoc]/@id" to redirect to the Thank you page). For some marketing actions, i need to parse the email value of the form to the URL like this for tracking purposes: 
http://www.mywebsite.com/thank-you.aspx?email=xxx@y.com&recordid=123456789

Since "@" is a reserved character, we can make it to "%40".

How can i do that? Any idea please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is possible. You could try writing a workflow that does a redirect? That MIGHT work, it depends if the workflows are carried out synchronously or not.

Another option is that the record ID is passed to the thank you page, you could write a bit of code to fetch the email address from the record using the Contour API, and manually run some tracking JS on page load.